# Shortening logical oeprations in Neo4j and Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How do you shorten the following query to present the same thing but with less words:

WHERE node.code <> 'a' AND node.code <> 'b' AND node.code <> 'c' AND node.code <> 'd' AND node.code <> 'e' AND node.code <> 'f'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a collection of the values you don't want, and perform a membership check:

```
WITH ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'] as excludedCodes
// though it's better to pass these in as a list parameter if you can
... // perform your matches and such
WHERE NOT node.code in excludedCodes
...
```